# Recursive call signature keeps changing

Tags: recursion, julia

I am going to implement a program that uses recursion quite a bit. So, before I started to get stack overflows exceptions, I figured it would be nice to have a trampoline implemented and use thunks in case it was needed.

A first try I did was with factorial. Here the code:

```
callable(f) = !isempty(methods(f))

function trampoline(f, arg1, arg2)
    v = f(arg1, arg2)
    while callable(v)
        v = v()
    end
return v
end

function factorial(n, continuation)
    if n == 1
        continuation(1)
    else
        (() -> factorial(n-1, (z -> (() -> continuation(n*z)))))
    end
end

function cont(x)
   x
end
```

Also, I implemented a naive factorial to check if, as a matter of fact, I would be preventing stack overflows:

```
function factorial_overflow(n)
    if n == 1
        1
    else
        n*factorial_overflow(n-1)
    end
end
```

The results are:

```
julia> factorial_overflow(140000)
ERROR: StackOverflowError:


#JITing with a small input
julia> trampoline(factorial, 10, cont)
3628800

#Testing
julia> trampoline(factorial, 140000, cont)
0
```

So, yes, I am avoiding StacksOverflows. And yes, I know the result is nonsense as I am getting integers overflows, but here I just cared about the stack. A production version of course would have that fixed.

(Also, I know for the factorial case there is a built-in, I wouldn't use either of these, I made them for testing my trampoline).

The trampoline version takes a lot of time when running for the first time, and then it gets quick... when computing the same or lower values.
If I did `trampoline(factorial, 150000, cont)` I will have some compiling time again.

It seems to me (educated guess) that I am JITing many different signatures for factorial: one for every thunk generated.

My question is: can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried changing `v` to an anonymous function? I think the fact that it's a generic function would cause some issues here.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thank you very much for your comment. Not sure I am following you; how could I loop on `v` if it is an anonymous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that every closure is its own type, which is specialized on the captured variables. To avoid this specialization, one can instead use functors, that are not fully specialized:

```
struct L1
    f
    n::Int
    z::Int
end

(o::L1)() = o.f(o.n*o.z)

struct L2
    f
    n::Int
end

(o::L2)(z) = L1(o.f, o.n, z)

struct Factorial
    f
    c
    n::Int
end

(o::Factorial)() = o.f(o.n-1, L2(o.c, o.n))

callable(f) = false
callable(f::Union{Factorial, L1, L2}) = true

function myfactorial(n, continuation)
    if n == 1
        continuation(1)
    else
        Factorial(myfactorial, continuation, n)
    end
end

function cont(x)
x
end

function trampoline(f, arg1, arg2)
    v = f(arg1, arg2)
    while callable(v)
        v = v()
    end
return v
end
```

Note that the function fields are untyped. Now the function run much faster on the first run:

```
julia> @time trampoline(myfactorial, 10, cont)
0.020673 seconds (4.24 k allocations: 264.427 KiB)
3628800

julia> @time trampoline(myfactorial, 10, cont)
0.000009 seconds (37 allocations: 1.094 KiB)
3628800

julia> @time trampoline(myfactorial, 14000, cont)
0.001277 seconds (55.55 k allocations: 1.489 MiB)
0

julia> @time trampoline(myfactorial, 14000, cont)
0.001197 seconds (55.55 k allocations: 1.489 MiB)
0
```

I just translated every closure in your code into a corresponding functor. This might not be needed and probably there are be better solutions, but it works and hopefully demonstrates the approach.

**Edit:**

To make the reason for the slowdown more clear, one can use:

```
function factorial(n, continuation)
    if n == 1
        continuation(1)
    else
        tmp = (z -> (() -> continuation(n*z)))
        @show typeof(tmp)
        (() -> factorial(n-1, tmp))
    end
end
```

This outputs:

```
julia> trampoline(factorial, 10, cont)
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,#cont}
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,#cont}}
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,#cont}}}
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,#cont}}}}
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,#cont}}}}}
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,#cont}}}}}}
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,#cont}}}}}}}
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,#cont}}}}}}}}
typeof(tmp) = ##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,##31#34{Int64,#cont}}}}}}}}}
3628800
```

`tmp` is a closure. Its automatically created type `##31#34` looks similar to

```
struct Tmp{T,F}
    n::T
    continuation::F
end
```

The specialization on the type `F` of the `continuation` field is the reason for the long compilation times.

By using `L2` instead, which is not specialized on the corresponding field `f`, the `continuation` argument to `factorial` has always the type `L2` and the problem is avoided.

Comment: That worked perfect! Thank you. However, I had to use `type` instead of `struct`. Keep looking at this, but this solves a big bottleneck. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you're now very close to having an implementation of an iterator with start/next/done.

Comment: @CristiánAntuña Sorry, I was using a nightly version of Julia 0.6. There, `struct` is the same as `immutable`. In this case, `type` (`mutable struct` on 0.6) is fine as well. @MattB. What do you mean? My code should be the same as the original code, just with manually implementated closures instead of automatic anonymous ones.

Comment: It's nothing too surprising — of course recursion can be represented by iteration.  The structure of that loop looks very much like the iterator protocol, and now that you have a custom object representing the factorial, you could similarly use start/next/done methods, and then just get the `last` element from the iterator.